# Is there an easy way to exclude files for which FuzzyFinder searches?

Tags: vim, fuzzyfinder

I am using FuzzyFinder and was wondering how I could instruct FuzzyFinder to exclude files it searches for. For now I have modified the plugin code but there must be a more easy way.

I want to exclude .class files from popping up in the result. Any hints/tips on how can I instruct FuzzyFinder to skip these files?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
let g:fuf_file_exclude = '\v\~$|\.o$|\.exe$|\.bak$|\.swp$|\.class$'
```

Use `:help fuf-options` for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i am still learning my way around vim and its plugins.

Comment: When you deploy a plugin, also deploy the doc, and run `:helptags /path/to/the/doc/folder`, almost all good plugins have a decent documentation here!

Comment: Remember the `\v` at the start if you want regular expressions! Also use `g:fuf_coveragefile_exclude` if you are using `FufCoverageFile`.

Answer (score 5):

With the help of Benoit:

```
"FuzzyFinder should ignore all files in .gitignore
let ignorefile = ".gitignore"
if filereadable(ignorefile)

  let ignore = '\v\~$'
  for line in readfile(ignorefile)
    let line = substitute(line, '\.', '\\.', 'g')
    let line = substitute(line, '\*', '.*', 'g')
    let ignore .= '|^' . line
  endfor

  let g:fuf_coveragefile_exclude = ignore
endif
```

And on the eighth day God was awakened by a terrible noise, and he did create a script to locate the subject of his disturbance.  Thereupon finding bugs, he smote them.  And it was good once more.

Comment: This definitely works from your `.vimrc` if you source your .vimrc after setting the `lcd` (local current directory), but if you switch tabs or windows to another project with a different `lcd`, you have to re-source your `.vimrc` and it clobbers the variable globally. Is there any way to do this per-window with different `lcd`s?

Comment: Make sure to set `g:fuf_file_exclude` and `g:fuf_dir_exclude` to the `ignore` variable as well. This will make `FufFile` and `FufDir` work as expected.

Comment: Thanks. One bugfix - should skip over empty lines

Answer (score 1):

This is the most automatic solution that will work in different windows and tabs that have their own `lcd` (local current directory).

Since Vimrc doensn't have the concept of setting exclude variables *per-window or per-tab*, you have to reset the exclude variables each time your run `FufFile` or related functions.

Put this in your `.vimrc`:

```
" FuzzyFinder
" -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
function! FufSetIgnore()

    let ignorefiles = [ $HOME . "/.gitignore", ".gitignore" ]
    let exclude_vcs = '\.(hg|git|bzr|svn|cvs)'
    let ignore = '\v\~$'

    for ignorefile in ignorefiles

        if filereadable(ignorefile)
            for line in readfile(ignorefile)
                if match(line, '^\s*$') == -1 && match(line, '^#') == -1
                    let line = substitute(line, '^/', '', '')
                    let line = substitute(line, '\.', '\\.', 'g')
                    let line = substitute(line, '\*', '.*', 'g')
                    let ignore .= '|^' . line
                endif
            endfor
        endif

        let ignore .= '|^' . exclude_vcs
        let g:fuf_coveragefile_exclude = ignore
        let g:fuf_file_exclude = ignore
        let g:fuf_dir_exclude = ignore

    endfor
endfunction

# Bonus: My custom key mappings for FuzzyFinder
# Calls the function to set the exclude variables, then runs FuzzyFinder
nn <Tab>   :call FufSetIgnore() <BAR> :FufFile<CR>
nn <S-Tab> :call FufSetIgnore() <BAR> :FufFile **/<CR>
nn <F3>    :call FufSetIgnore() <BAR> :FufFile **/<CR>
```

Comment: This is really cool, but for some reason, it doesn't seem to actually work the first time I call FF. I have a very large file tree (and i don't need to index the dependencies), and each first load takes almost a minute. Is there some way to have this run before fuzzy finder tries to build an index at all?